# Microsoft Azure login with AWS cognito for multi-tenant and personal account

Tags: reactjs, azure, amazon-cognito

Is there anyway to integrate Azure (multi-tenant and personal account) Login in Amazon Cognito?

The application's manifest is

> "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

In Amazon Cognito console, I tried to add OIDC Provider, issuer is [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/v2.0). It works with my tenant users. But it doesn't work for other tenant users and personal accounts. I see it's because issuer endpoint has my tenant_id.

I tried to use https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0, the Azure AD login works for multi-tenant and personal accounts, but cognito doesn't get token.

> OAuth - Error handling auth response. Error:
> Bad+id_token+issuer+https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2F58a488e4-8111-40be-a23b-f9531d464895%2Fv2.0

Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: I found one solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331213/microsoft-oidc-in-aws-cognito-allowing-multiple-tenants It's now solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft oidc in AWS Cognito allowing multiple tenants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331213/microsoft-oidc-in-aws-cognito-allowing-multiple-tenants)